# Stored procedure doesn't compile

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I wrote this stored procedure and know the individual queries in there work. I just implemented a standardized template across the company which is used for exception flow.

```
USE [DEV_SERV]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [sch].[usp_tmSetstat]
      @stat VARCHAR(50), 
      @statDesc VARCHAR(50), 
      @Parent_stat VARCHAR(50), 
      @Status SMALLINT

AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON                        

      DECLARE @Parent HIERARCHYID 
      DECLARE @Sibling HIERARCHYID

      DECLARE @OldParent HIERARCHYID 
      DECLARE @NewParent HIERARCHYID
      DECLARE @CurrentPos HIERARCHYID

      DECLARE @StatusInactiveKey SMALLINT 

    BEGIN TRY

            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [sch].[stat_path] WHERE [stat_code] = @stat)
            BEGIN
                  SET @OldParent = (SELECT [stat_path] AS tmpPath 
                     FROM   [sch].[stat]  
                     WHERE  stat_code = 
                     (SELECT s.parent_stat_code 
                              FROM [sch].[stat_path] s WHERE s.stat_code = @stat))

                  SET @NewParent = (SELECT [stat_path] AS tmpPath 
                     FROM   [sch].[stat] 
                     WHERE  t.stat_code = @Parent_stat);

                  SET @CurrentPos =  (SELECT [stat_path] AS tmpPath 
                     FROM   [sch].[stat] 
                     WHERE  t.stat_code = @stat);

                  UPDATE [sch].[stat] SET 
                        stat_path = @CurrentPos.GetReparentedValue(@OldParent, @NewParent)
                              WHERE stat_key = @stat                              
                  GO
            END

            ELSE        
            BEGIN
                  SET @Parent = (SELECT [stat_path] AS tmpPath 
                     FROM   [sch].[stat] t 
                     WHERE  t.stat_code = @Parent_stat) 

                  SET @Sibling = (SELECT TOP 1 [stat_path] 
                     FROM   [sch].[stat] t 
                     WHERE  parent_stat_code = @Parent_stat 
                     ORDER  BY t.stat_key DESC) 

                  SET @StatusInactiveKey = [dbo].[udf_GetStatusKey]('Active')

                  INSERT INTO [sch].[stat] 
                                    ([stat_code], 
                                     [stat_desc], 
                                     [stat_path], 
                                     [point_type], 
                                     [status_key]) 
                  VALUES      (@stat, 
                                     @statDesc, 
                                     @Parent.GetDescendant(@Sibling, NULL), 
                                     'T', 
                                     @StatusInactiveKey) 
                  GO    
            END

      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH       

      END CATCH
END
```

However I get these annoying errors that are like;

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_tmSetstat, Line 60
Incorrect syntax near '@stat'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@Parent_stat".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@Parent_stat".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Must declare the scalar variable "@StatusInactiveKey".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 24
Must declare the scalar variable "@stat".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@stat".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@errTemplate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
Must declare the scalar variable "@errTemplate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
Must declare the scalar variable "@errTemplate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@errTemplate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@errTemplate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Must declare the scalar variable "@errProcedure".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@errNumber".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Must declare the scalar variable "@errLine".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@errSeverity".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@errState".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 18
Must declare the scalar variable "@errProcedure".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 20
Must declare the scalar variable "@errTemplate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 25
Must declare the scalar variable "@RetVal".
```

I pasted my whole stored proc in there, does anyone know what's wrong? Was i supposed to declare something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `GO` statement in the middle of your Stored Proc. Remove it, and you should be good.

Comment: so where should i place the go statement then if i want the changes to commit?

Comment: Uhm - I think you're misunderstanding what the GO statement does. Basically, SQL Server Management Studio sends your code to the SQL Server in batches. `GO` signals the end of a batch. You cannot split a stored procedure across multiple batches. In general, you can never have a `GO` statement inside a BEGIN-END construct.

Comment: If you are trying to control how and when data is committed to tables, you must use [transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929(v=sql.105).aspx) (BEGIN TRANS/COMMIT TRANS).